# Concerning formula issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a new question concerning formulas in Excel. Thing is, I have a sheet, *sheet2*, containing dates and values. Currently I am using a combination of the **index()** and **match()** functions in to fetch different values, according to certain conditions - one being the date, from *sheet2* into another sheet, *sheet1*, .

The data in *sheet2*, *will be updated from time to time* wherefore certain dates in the data will obviously "disappear" and of course, yield an error in the **index-match** formulae, not being able to find the value at hand.

My question is then, if there is an easy way to write the formula so that if the date we try to find from *sheet1* is *less* than the current date, transform current value into constant value. The pseudo code would be something like,

```
IF date_to_find from sheet1 IN sheet2 > todays_date Then
    Set value to constant (do not evaluate formula)
Else
    Find value in sheet2 where the dates are matched in both sheet1 and sheet2
End
```

I know the easiest way might be to just implement the whole thing in VBA, but just wanted to check if anyone had a nicer solution.

Current formula in *sheet1* is

```
'A872 = "2013-05-17"
'F872 is the goal cell (containing formula)
'$A$1:$K$100 contains date in format "yyyy-mm-dd" (given as column)
'$A$2:$K$2 contains currencies (given as row)
'$A$3:$K$3 contains text (also given as row)

 IFERROR(INDEX('sheet2'!$A$1:$K$100;MATCH(A872;'sheet2'!$A$1:$A$100;0);_
        MATCH(1;('sheet2'!$A$2:$K$2="EUR")*('sheet2'!$A$3:$K$3="Matching text");0));"")
```

So, if current date is "2013-05-17", the formula evaluates perfectly and returns, say, 400.000. But *tomorrow*, "2013-05-18", there is no need to change the cell (2013-05-17 value has past), so I would now like to FIX this value, so that the formula doesn't try and find "2013-05-17" in *sheet2* no more. I.e. I want cell **F872** to just say "400.000", and not "IFERROR(INDEX(...)"

Thanks,
Niklas

Answer (score 1):

You could just wrap your formula in an IF-statement like this:

```
=IF(A872<TODAY(),[your formula],[constant value])
```